# VirusTotal HTTPS connection Java

Tags: java, https

I am looking to parse a VirusTotal URL, therefor I'm trying to open a connection to the specific link and read the web-page source.

I'm using this code

```
package boot;

import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.security.cert.Certificate;
import java.io.*;
import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
import javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException;

public class Run {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Run().testIt();
    }
    private void testIt() {
        String https_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7b6b268cbca9d421aabba5f08533d3dcaba50e0f7887b07ef2bd66bf218b35ff/analysis/";
        URL url;
        try{
            url = new URL(https_url);
            HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            // dumpl all cert info
            print_https_cert(con);
            System.out.println(con);
            // dump all the content
            print_content(con);
        } catch(MalformedURLException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch(IOException e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    private void print_https_cert(HttpsURLConnection con) {
        if(con != null){
            try{
                System.out.println(con);
                System.out.println("Response Code : " + con.getResponseCode());
                System.out.println("Cipher Suite : " + con.getCipherSuite());
                System.out.println("\n");
                Certificate[] certs = con.getServerCertificates();
                for(Certificate cert : certs){
                    System.out.println("Cert Type : " + cert.getType());
                    System.out.println("Cert Hash Code : " + cert.hashCode());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Algorithm : " + cert.getPublicKey().getAlgorithm());
                    System.out.println("Cert Public Key Format : " + cert.getPublicKey().getFormat());
                    System.out.println("\n");
                }
            } catch(SSLPeerUnverifiedException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
    private void print_content(HttpsURLConnection con) {
        if(con != null){
            try{
                System.out.println("****** Content of the URL ********");
                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String input;
                while((input = br.readLine()) != null){
                    System.out.println(input);
                }
                br.close();
            } catch(IOException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but I get this error

```
Response Code : 200
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: connection not yet open
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getCipherSuite(Unknown Source)
    at boot.Run.print_https_cert(Run.java:38)
    at boot.Run.testIt(Run.java:23)
    at boot.Run.main(Run.java:13)
```

I've tried doing some testing and adjustments but I didn't manage to make it work.

I've also tested couple of other websites and it worked just fine.

Thank you.

Comment: I tried your code and I have the same results. My best guess is that virustotal has some anti-robot logic in place that prevents the server from returning the data. I tried adding a User-Agent to the request but that didn't help either. Not sure what else to try at this point and it's late for me so I'll think about it some more and get back to you if something comes to mind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This code fails because a simple GET request without headers is "rejected" by VirusTotal. Try to provide more information like below and it will work.

```
    private void testIt() {
    String https_url = "https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/7b6b268cbca9d421aabba5f08533d3dcaba50e0f7887b07ef2bd66bf218b35ff/analysis/";        
    URL url;
    try{
        url = new URL(https_url);
        HttpsURLConnection con = (HttpsURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        con.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; U; Intel Mac OS X 10.4; en-US; rv:1.9.2.2) Gecko/20100316 Firefox/3.6.2");
        con.setRequestProperty("accept-language", "en-US,en;q=0.8");
        con.setRequestProperty("accept", "text/html");
        //May need to use connect() if connection is not established
        //con.connect();

        // dumpl all cert info
        print_https_cert(con);
        System.out.println(con);
        // dump all the content
        print_content(con);
    } catch(MalformedURLException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch(IOException e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, just copying the properties made it work, appreciate it.